# A continuous $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ such that $\frac{f(x)+f(y)}2 \le f(\sqrt{xy}\,).$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Assume $f:[0,1] \to R$ is continuous and for every $x,y\in [0,1]$ we have
$$\frac{f(x)+f(y)}2 \le f(\sqrt{xy}).$$
Prove $\int_0^1f(x)dx \le f(e^{-1})$.

i found out that $max(f) = f(0)$ and $min(f) = f(1)$. and i could relate this function to concave function(with $g(x):=f(e^x)$)... but i couldn't go further. any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: @Math_QED I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Show by induction that

$$\frac{1}{2^n}\cdot \sum_{k=1}^{2^n}f(x_k) \le f(\,(x_1x_2\cdots x_{2^n}\,)^{1/2^n}).$$

Comment: it's wonderful... thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Write $g(u) = f(\exp(-u)).$ The conditions on $f$ imply $g:\mathbb R^+\to \mathbb R$ is concave, so by Jensen's inequality $$\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx = \int_0^\infty \exp(-u) g(u)\, du \le g\left(\int_0^\infty u \exp(-u) \,du\right) = g(1) = f(e^{-1}).$$

Comment: thank you for this elegant answer. i'have never seen this form of Jensen's inequality. how can i prove it? @kimchi lover

Comment: Jensen's inequality is usually stated for convex functions.  It also applies, with inequalities reversed, to concave functions.  (If $g$ is concave, $-g$ is convex: nothing deeper than that going on here.)  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Form_involving_a_probability_density_function for the form I used.  For me the crucial  part was guessing to do the log transform to convert the geometric mean into an arithmetic mean.  Everything else is calculus.